# After adding caching site still takes as long

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to cache the return statement for logged out profiles. [And eventually for logged in profiles if possible, but what that returns depends on the user settings and is more complex]. Note that I am using Heroku.

According to new relic and the Chrome -Network the site takes just as long.

Anyways this is what I did.

```
  caches_action :logged_out_list

  def index
    if logged_in_profile
      #do something that calls a select queries based on the profile that's logged in
    else
      logged_out_list
    end
  end

 def logged_out_list
    Profile.all_public.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 12)
 end
```

So what I did was add these lines to config/application.rb

For the record, I don't know if this is a problem, but I had a Gem installed locally that

```
config.cache_store = :memory_store
config.cache_store = :memory_store, { size: 64.megabytes }
```

Also added the gem

```
gem 'actionpack-action_caching'
```

## EDIT

It isn't working locally, I know because upon refreshing the console shows the select statement and what not. I set caching to true in development.rb btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`logged_out_list` isn't an action (it's just a method that's being called by your `index` action), so using `cache_action` isn't going to work.

Two options:

1. Switch to fragment caching. It's more flexible, and you don't need an extra gem.
2. Cache the index action and do something fancy with the `if` option:

```rb
caches_action :index, if: Proc.new do
  !logged_in_profile?(request)
end
```

Comment: What do you mean switch to partials? How would that help? I am trying to display something for logged out users that changes a few times a day and for logged in users it's an entirely different story

Comment: Sorry, fragment caching, not partials. Used the wrong word :-)

Comment: if logged in, don't pull from cache. if logged out, pull from cache? all done in the view -- is this what you mean?

Comment: It would need in the view, yeah. I don't think you can just cache the call to render.

Answer (score 1):

As James pointed out, you cannot cache the method with `caches_action`, but you can write to the cache directly:

```
def logged_out_list
  cache.fetch("logged_out_list_#{params[:page].to_i}")
    Profile.all_public.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 12)
  end
end
```

See [`cache.fetch`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Store.html#method-i-fetch).